# RSpec did nothing after rails upgrade from 3.0 to 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bundle

So, the problem is: Rails project was upgraded from 3.0 to 3.1 and after that command

```
rake spec
```

or

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

doesn't show anything. And with --trace the same.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your `Gemfile.lock` and running `bundle` again?

Comment: Yes, but nothing changes

Comment: Have you tried running rails `generate rspec:install`, which performs the initialization tasks including creation the `rake spec` task.  It should leve your current tests untouched but make sure you have a backup.  If that does not work will you post the contents of your `Rakefile`.

Comment: [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159402/should-i-use-rake-spec-or-rspec-cant-get-rake-spec-to-work#comment16272030_12159402) solution fixes the issue for me